# find records belonging to same row in sqlite database in android

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite, relational-database

In my app i have textfield for source co-ordinates(users location) and destination co-ordinates. I want to find out whether there are any records in my database (bus stops) which are close to these co-ordinates . Essentially i want to find which bus stops are closest to users location and destination location for that i am using following code.

**for source**

```
public ArrayList<String> countDatabase(Double LAT, Double LNG) {
    String sourcename=null;
    double min_distance=99999999;
    ArrayList<String> sList = new ArrayList<>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor mCount= db.rawQuery("SELECT snme FROM halt_details WHERE slati BETWEEN '" +LAT+"- 0.1' AND '"+LAT+" + 0.1' AND slng BETWEEN '" +LNG+"- 0.1' AND '"+LNG+" + 0.1'", null);
    mCount.moveToFirst();
    while (mCount.moveToNext()) {
        double Latitude = mCount.getDouble(2);
        double Longitude = mCount.getDouble(3);
        double dis=Math.sqrt( (Latitude-LAT)*(Latitude-LAT) + (Longitude-LNG)*(Longitude-LNG) );
        if (dis<min_distance){
            sourcename=mCount.getString(1);
            sList.add(sourcename);
        }
    }
    mCount.close();
   return sList;
}
```

In the end i get an array list(slist) which contains name of all the stops near to users location calculated using eulers distance formula. Same procedure is applied to destination to get list(dlist). 
Now i want to know wheteher any stations in that list lies in the same row in my database, for that

```
for(int i=0;i<ssize;i++){
            String source = ssList.get(i);
            for(int j=0;j<dsize;j++) {
                String destination = ddList.get(j);
                Boolean b = myDb.findBus(source, destination);
                if(b){
                    TextView tvv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView7);
                    tvv.setText(source+" and "+destination);
                }
            }

        }
```

**findBus**

```
 public Boolean findBus(String sourcename, String desname){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor mCount= db.rawQuery("select count(*) from search_table where name='" + sourcename + "' AND dname='"+desname+"'", null);
    mCount.moveToFirst();
    int count= mCount.getInt(0);
    mCount.close();
    if (count>0) return true;
    else return false;
}
```

but i cant seem to run this code, facing error in

```
 Cursor mCount= db.rawQuery("SELECT snme FROM halt_details WHERE slati BETWEEN '" +LAT+"- 0.1' AND '"+LAT+" + 0.1' AND slng BETWEEN '" +LNG+"- 0.1' AND '"+LNG+" + 0.1'", null);
```

error says

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick

**full code**

**DatabaseHelper**

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Nearby.db";
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "halt_details";
public static final String COL_2 = "snme";
public static final String COL_3 = "slati";
public static final String COL_4 = "slong";
public static final String COL_5 = "dnme";
public static final String COL_6 = "dlati";
public static final String COL_7 = "dlong";
public static final String COL_8 = "buses";

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, snme VARCHAR, slati DOUBLE, slong DOUBLE, dnme VARCHAR, dlati DOUBLE, dlong DOUBLE, buses VARCHAR)");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}

public void insertData(String sname, Double slat, Double slng, String dname, Double dlat, Double dlng, String bus) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put("snme",sname);
    contentValues.put("slati",slat);
    contentValues.put("slong",slng);
    contentValues.put("dnme",dname);
    contentValues.put("dlati",dlat);
    contentValues.put("dlong",dlng);
    contentValues.put("buses",bus);

    db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null ,contentValues);
}

public void clearDatabase() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String clearDBQuery = "DELETE FROM "+TABLE_NAME;
    db.execSQL(clearDBQuery);
}

public ArrayList<String> countDatabase(Double LAT, Double LNG) {
    String sourcename=null;
    double min_distance=99999999;
    ArrayList<String> sList = new ArrayList<>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor mCount= db.rawQuery("SELECT snme FROM halt_details WHERE slati BETWEEN '" +LAT+"- 0.1' AND '"+LAT+" + 0.1' AND slng BETWEEN '" +LNG+"- 0.1' AND '"+LNG+" + 0.1'", null);
    mCount.moveToFirst();
    while (mCount.moveToNext()) {
        double Latitude = mCount.getDouble(2);
        double Longitude = mCount.getDouble(3);
        double dis=Math.sqrt( (Latitude-LAT)*(Latitude-LAT) + (Longitude-LNG)*(Longitude-LNG) );
        if (dis<min_distance){
            sourcename=mCount.getString(1);
            sList.add(sourcename);
        }
    }
    mCount.close();
   return sList;
}

public ArrayList<String> countDatabase1(Double LAT, Double LNG) {
    String destinationname=null;
    ArrayList<String> dList = new ArrayList<>();
    double min_distance=99999999;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor mCount= db.rawQuery("SELECT snme FROM halt_details WHERE slati BETWEEN '" +LAT+"- 0.1' AND '"+LAT+" + 0.1' AND slng BETWEEN '" +LNG+"- 0.1' AND '"+LNG+" + 0.1'", null);
    mCount.moveToFirst();
    while (mCount.moveToNext()) {
        double Latitude = mCount.getDouble(2);
        double Longitude = mCount.getDouble(3);
        double dis=Math.sqrt( (Latitude-LAT)*(Latitude-LAT) + (Longitude-LNG)*(Longitude-LNG) );
        if (dis<min_distance){
            destinationname = mCount.getString(4);
            dList.add(destinationname);

        }
    }
    mCount.close();
    return dList;
}

public Boolean findBus(String sourcename, String desname){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor mCount= db.rawQuery("select count(*) from search_table where name='" + sourcename + "' AND dname='"+desname+"'", null);
    mCount.moveToFirst();
    int count= mCount.getInt(0);
    mCount.close();
    if (count>0) return true;
    else return false;
}


public Cursor getAllData() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from " + TABLE_NAME, null);
    return res;
}
```

}

**Result.java**

```
public class result extends Activity {
DatabaseHelper myDb;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_result);
    String url = getIntent().getExtras().getString("username");
    String url1 = getIntent().getExtras().getString("username1");
    TextView tv= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    TextView tv1= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView5);
    tv.setText(url);
    tv1.setText(url1);

    String[] separated = url.split("_");
    String srclat = separated[0];
        Double dsrclat= Double.parseDouble(srclat);
    String srclng = separated[1];
        Double dsrclng= Double.parseDouble(srclng);

    String[] separated1 = url.split("_");
    String deslat = separated1[0];
         Double ddeslat= Double.parseDouble(deslat);
    String deslng = separated1[1];
         Double ddeslng= Double.parseDouble(deslng);

}

public void Database(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(result.this, feeder.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}


public void NearestValue(View view){


    TextView tv= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    String s1 = tv.getText().toString();
    String[] separated = s1.split("_");
    String deslat = separated[0];
    Double Lat= Double.parseDouble(deslat);
    String deslng = separated[1];
    Double Lng= Double.parseDouble(deslng);
    ArrayList<String> ssList = new ArrayList<>();
    ssList = myDb.countDatabase(Lat,Lng);
    int ssize = ssList.size();
    TextView tvvv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView8);
    for(int i=0;i<ssize;i++) {
        tvvv.setText(ssList.get(i));
    }

    TextView tv1= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView5);
    String s11 = tv1.getText().toString();
    String[] separated1 = s11.split("_");
    String deslat1 = separated1[0];
    Double Lat1= Double.parseDouble(deslat1);
    String deslng1 = separated1[1];
    Double Lng1= Double.parseDouble(deslng1);
    ArrayList<String> ddList = new ArrayList<>();
    ddList = myDb.countDatabase1(Lat1,Lng1);
    int dsize = ddList.size();
    TextView tvvvv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView9);
    for(int i=0;i<dsize;i++) {
        tvvv.setText(ddList.get(i));
    }

        for(int i=0;i<ssize;i++){
            String source = ssList.get(i);
            for(int j=0;j<dsize;j++) {
                String destination = ddList.get(j);
                Boolean b = myDb.findBus(source, destination);
                if(b){
                    TextView tvv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView7);
                    tvv.setText(source+" and "+destination);
                }
            }

        }

    }

}
```

**result,xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="136dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="84dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_marginTop="97dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/nearest"
    android:layout_marginEnd="14dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="88dp"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/nearest"
    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    tools:text="tv" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/nearest"
    android:layout_width="130sp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:onClick="NearestValue"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/gotodb"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/gotodb"
    android:layout_marginTop="76dp"
    android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
    android:shadowColor="#6C74A8"
    android:shadowDx="6"
    android:shadowDy="0"
    android:shadowRadius="9"
    android:text="nearest bus stop"
    android:textColor="#43456B"
    android:textColorLink="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.95" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/gotodb"
    android:layout_width="130sp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
    android:onClick="Database"

    android:text="database"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
    android:textColorLink="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
    android:textSize="15sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView8"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/nearest"
    android:layout_marginEnd="38dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/textView5"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView9"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView8"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_marginTop="31dp"
    android:text="TextView" />
```

Comment: Show the complete stack trace.

Comment: actually i resolved that error but now i am faced with another difficulty a mentioned in edited question. By the way stack trace for "Show only selected application" is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following, *assuming for arguments sake that LAT is 10 and LNG is 30*, :-

```
Cursor mCount= db.rawQuery("SELECT snme FROM halt_details WHERE slati BETWEEN '" +LAT+"- 0.1' AND '"+LAT+" + 0.1' AND slng BETWEEN '" +LNG+"- 0.1' AND '"+LNG+" + 0.1'", null);
```

equates to :-

```
SELECT snme FROM halt_details 
    WHERE slati BETWEEN '10- 0.1' AND '10+ 0.1' 
        AND slng BETWEEN '30- 0.1' AND '30+ 0.1';
```

The first issue you have is that there is no column **slng** it should in fact be **slong** (at least according to the code you have shown).

Making this change will result in the query running but that it would be unlikely that the results would be what is required (most likely retrieve nothing). This is because you have enclosed the the numeric values in single quotes making them an entire string such as **10- 0.1**. The arithmetic will not be performed the range will be between the strings.

Rather the resultant SQL should be something like :-

```
SELECT snme FROM halt_details 
    WHERE slati BETWEEN 10-0.1 AND (10+0.1) 
    AND slong BETWEEN (30-0.1) AND (30+0.1);
```

So the code would be :-

```
Cursor mCount= db.rawQuery("SELECT snme FROM halt_details WHERE slati BETWEEN (" +LAT+"- 0.1) AND "+LAT+" + 0.1) AND slong BETWEEN (" +LNG+"- 0.1) AND ("+LNG+" + 0.1)", null);
```

However, you would not have encountered the first error if you used the available variables holding column names. So the above could be :-

```
Cursor mCount= db.rawQuery("SELECT " + DatabaseHelper.COL_2 + " FROM " + DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME + "s WHERE " + DatabaseHelper.COL_3 + " BETWEEN (" +LAT+"- 0.1) AND "+LAT+" + 0.1) AND " + DatabaseHelper.COL_4 + " BETWEEN (" +LNG+"- 0.1) AND ("+LNG+" + 0.1)", null);
```

- Of course this methodology of relying on a single definition could be employed throughout.

You also appear to have mistakes in Moving throughout the resultant cursor and also when trying to extract data. As an example take the code :-

```
Cursor mCount= db.rawQuery("SELECT snme FROM halt_details WHERE slati BETWEEN '" +LAT+"- 0.1' AND '"+LAT+" + 0.1' AND slng BETWEEN '" +LNG+"- 0.1' AND '"+LNG+" + 0.1'", null);
mCount.moveToFirst();
while (mCount.moveToNext()) {
    double Latitude = mCount.getDouble(2);
    double Longitude = mCount.getDouble(3);
    double dis=Math.sqrt( (Latitude-LAT)*(Latitude-LAT) + (Longitude-LNG)*(Longitude-LNG) );
    if (dis<min_distance){
        destinationname = mCount.getString(4);
        dList.add(destinationname);

    }
}
mCount.close();
```

The query will return a cursor say with 2 rows. Each row will have a single column named **snme**.

First you move to the first row, you then move to the next row. So the 2 rows are now 1. (removing the line `mCount.moveToFirst();` will result in all rows being processed).

You then attempt to get the cursor column at offset 2 (the third column). However, the Cursor only has a single column so you will get an error. The Same with offset 3. The only column that exists in the Cursor is offset 0.

Assuming that you want the additional columns, the simplest fix could be to code :-

```
Cursor mCount= db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM halt_details WHERE slati BETWEEN '" +LAT+"- 0.1' AND '"+LAT+" + 0.1' AND slng BETWEEN '" +LNG+"- 0.1' AND '"+LNG+" + 0.1'", null);
```

- - equates to get all columns.
- note corrections noted above have not been included in the above.All the above is showing is how to get all columns.

**Note** the above code has not been tested and is intended solely as being in-principle.

Comment: I am kind of a newb in java... but your explanation was very clear.... thanks a lot... i have been waiting for answer from 2-3 days